# Dependency not found

Tags: java, maven

What can I do when old pom.xml version of jars are not supported by maven now.

For example:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.11</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Maven is not able to download this version of jar.
When I click to download jar from this site: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-core/6.4.11

then I get:

> {
>     "errors" : [ {
>       "status" : 404,
>       "message" : "Could not find resource"
>     } ]
>   }

Comment: This url is working. Could you please try again.

Comment: for me not :(   ,

Comment: This artifact is not in Maven Central....  https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.atlassian.jira

Answer (score 4):

Please note the string `Note: this artifact it located at AtlassianPkgs repository (https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-public/)` at the bottom of https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-core/6.4.11

You can add AtlassianPkgs to you repos or use new version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-core/1000.30.0

Comment: Oh i See, thx. And what can I do if I want a maven download it automaticaly by my IDE?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with old version you can add to your pom

```
<repository>
  <id>atlassian-public</id>
  <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/mvn/maven-external/</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
  </snapshots>
   <releases>
     <enabled>true</enabled>
     <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
  </releases>
```

I found it in `https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/working-with-maven/`

Or just update version.